# Is this an example for $[E:\Bbb R]$=4?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, field-theory, extension-field, real-numbers

Consider the polynomial $x^4+1$. Note that this is irreducible in $\Bbb R[x]$. Therefore the quotient $\Bbb R[x]/ <x^4+1>$ is a field, which is a degree 4 extension over $\Bbb R$. However, from this question ([No extension to complex numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142330/no-extension-to-complex-numbers)), and from intution, it seems that this is impossible because $[\Bbb C:\Bbb R]=2$. This is sort of out of my head. Can someone help me clear this up? Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, any polynomial of degree $3$ or higher in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is reducible. It's not so hard to prove, and the hint is to write the polynomial first as a product of linear factors in $\mathbb{C}[x]$!

Answer (score 4):

> Note that this is irreducible in $\Bbb R[x]$

$$x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

Who says it's irreducible?

$$(x^2 - \sqrt{2} x + 1)(x^2 + \sqrt{2} x + 1)$$

Comment: Who? Leibniz, for one! (according to Bourbaki's Historical Note at the end of chapters IV-V of his Algebra, page A. V. 188)