# converting 2-Tuple of real numbers in to a field

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, field-theory

I understand the requirement of a set to be field and the 2-tuple of real numbers is a set on which addition and multiplication is defined in a certain way so as to make that set a field (complex numbers). I was just wondering if there is other way to define addition and multiplication which would still make the 2-Tuple of real numbers a Field? and why is it limited to 2-tuples. Is there a field of 3-tuples as well?

Comment: The way I see it, satisfying multiplication properties using other properties, is very tough. So are there any other definitions which may make 2-tuples a field

Comment: You might be interested in "quaternions", and in the story of how Hamilton came up with them.

Comment: But the multiplication is not commutative, is it? Thanks for reference about the extension of complex numbers

Comment: That's right, multiplication in the quaternions is not commutative – but it's the best you can do in any dimension exceeding 2.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about my original question? Can 2-tuples be defined in different way to get a field?

Comment: Depends how far you're willing to go. The set $S$ of all ordered pairs of reals is just a set of the cardinality of the continuum, so you could take any field $F$ of that cardinality, let $g:S\to F$ be any bijection, and define a field structure on $S$ by $a+b=g^{-1}(g(a)+g(b))$, $ab=g^{-1}(g(a)g(b))$. This will, in general, destroy all the usual structure on $S$. You might want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142330/no-extension-to-complex-numbers