# Are there any number fields that extend $\mathbb C$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

If there are number fields that extend $\mathbb C$, what are some examples?

Comment: consider the definition of number field

Comment: A number field is necessarily countable.

Comment: If rather than [*number field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field), you are asking if there are simply any *fields* that extend $\Bbb C$, you may be interested in reading about Quaternions and other hypercomplex number systems, but several of these fail to be fields.  The quaternions are not commutative with respect to multiplication for instance.

Comment: See [No extension to complex numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142330/no-extension-to-complex-numbers)

Comment: @JMoravitz Or just $\Bbb C(X)$

Comment: If you're asking whether there are any finite (or generally algebraic) extensions of $\mathbb{C}$, then no; it's algebraically closed.

Comment: @JMoravitz no hypercomplex numbers are fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number field is, by definition, a finite extension of the rationals and so the simple answer to your question is "no".

Moreover, the field of complex numbers is itself closed. In other words all polynomials over this field completely factorise and so the complex numbers cannot be extended in the way you are probably thinking.

There are however larger algebraic structures which do contain the complex numbers. For example, the complex number $a+bi$ can be thought of as the 2x2 matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a&-b \\b&a\\\end{pmatrix}$$ and these matrices are contained in the much larger set of all 2x2 matrices with real entries.

As pointed out by @JMoravitz the complete set of such 2x2 matrices is **not** a field since their multiplication is not (in general) commutative.

Comment: It is worth explicitly pointing out that general matrices are not necessarily commutative with respect to multiplication.

Comment: Nor are what would come to my mind, quaternions.

Comment: Yes @JMoravitz I think this added comment might be very useful for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean as a number, but both the field of rational functions, holomorphic functions, or linear operators on them, are extensions of complex numbers, because they include complex numbers as constants.